# Jenkins unable to launch slave agent via SSH - disconnected overnight

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have a set of Jenkins slaves that were connected via SSH. They have all been working fine for several months. This morning, I found that all slaves were disconnected, and all had the same error when I tried to launch the agent:

```
01/05/18 16:27:13] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/home/ubuntu/jenkins_slave" && java  -jar slave.jar
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

Slave JVM has not reported exit code. Is it still running?
[01/05/18 16:27:20] Launch failed - cleaning up connection

[01/05/18 16:27:20] [SSH] Connection closed.
ERROR: Connection terminated
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2638)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:853)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73)
```

One common issue I found was a mismatch between Jenkins and Java versions, but I believe mine are compatible (Jenkins server says 2.46.3 and the slaves all have Java 1.7).

Regarding "Is it still running?", I don't see a Jenkins slave process running:

```
ps aux | grep java
```

returns nothing.

I have been unable to locate any Jenkins logs on the slave side. All the logs I've found on the master side only reiterate the error pasted above.

Comment: Have you updated the server or slaves lately?

Comment: I haven't made any updates to server or slaves recently

Comment: The code that you reported can be found in https://github.com/jenkinsci/remoting/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/remoting/SynchronousExecutorService.java it seems like the comunications with jenkins server failed at some point

Comment: I still don't know for sure what caused the issue, but it was resolved by simply restarting the Jenkins master. Everything was properly connected when it came back up.